# Temperature Sensor with Current Sensor

Tags: battery

I have **SMA - Sunny Island** inverter, the one that is use in Off-Grid Solar PV System.

I am getting error because there is no **Battery Temperature Sensor** connected.

I have a plan on buying the dedicated Temperature Sensor for this inverter but for the mean time I want to create a substitute for this sensor because I am chasing the deadline.

This is the picture of their Battery Temperature Sensor

[image]

and this is where it must be connected

[image]

I don't know what's the circuit inside their Bat Temp Sensor but looking at the inverter where it is going to plug, it says that it has 4-pins, 2-pins for battery temperature and the remaining 2-pins is for battery current.

Do you have an idea on what their battery sensor diagram looks like?

Comment: The 2 wire temp sensor is probably a thecouple but the type? who knows. type J and K are very popular as far as the current sensor there are many types most of the equipment I support I use use CT's, current transformers they develop a voltage based on the current flowing these are even harder to guess at because the ratio is needed to develop the correct voltage for the protection.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recommend that.

The battery temperature sensor is an absolutely *necessary* piece of safety. Substituting it for a dummy is not an option.

Substituting it for an equivalent sensor is an option, but not based on the amount of information you have.

So, lest you want your *dead*line to actually have something to do with the *death* of someone (or at least a battery pack and inverter), tell your boss or client that you'll need time for components to arrive. Engineering is about knowing where to put priorities.